# javascript fails when populating array

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I run the following javascript, it fails when `input_array[input_array.length] = id;` is not commented out. Can anyone see what is causing this?

```
function cat_images_low_lag () {
    var input_array = new array ();

    cat_images = $(".category-description").next().find("img");
    cat_images.each(function () { 
        url = $(this).parent().attr("href");
        id = url.split("id=");
        id = id[1];

        input_array[input_array.length] = id;
    });
    alert ("trst");
    alert(input_array.join("\n"));
}
```

cheers!

Comment: It should be `Array`, capital "A", or better yet just `var input_array = [];`

Comment: Also you should be declaring "id" and "url" with `var` !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, replace:

```
var input_array = new array ();
```

With:

```
var input_array = new Array();
```

And use this to insert:

```
input_array.push(id);
```

Or directly add:

```
input_array[input_array.length] = id;
```

Other ways to initialize arrays:

```
var input_array = [];
```

Comment: or even `var input_array = []`

Comment: @HBP Yes, you can... :) Added it too! :)

Comment: forgot javascript is case sensitive!

Answer (score 1):

Others noted the capitalization problem, but since you're using jQuery, a nicer way to build the Array is like this:

```
function cat_images_low_lag () {
    var input_array = $(".category-description + * img").map(function () { 
        return this.parentNode.href.split("id=")[1];
    }).toArray();

    alert ("trst");
    alert(input_array.join("\n"));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that your query selector is correct. I believe `next` selects only the next sibling, while `+ *` would select all elements that follow `.category-description`.

Comment: @Shmiddty: You're thinking of the `~` selector. :) The `+` selects only the next element sibling.

Comment: You're right. I tend to use the `+` selector in the context of `li`, so it ends up styling all elements but the first `li`, but only because each is immediately preceded by an `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization of the array is incorrect

```
var input_array = new array ();
```

You should use the shorthand

```
var input_array = [];
```

or

```
var input_array = new Array();
```

Moreover, to avoid having cat_images be a variable in the global scope, you may want to consider scoping it locally like this

```
var cat_images = $(".category-description").next().find("img");
```

Comment: It's OK in JavaScript for the index to be greater than the array length. The language explicitly supports that.